# How to enable compression in WAMP installed on Windows Server?

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008, wamp

How to enable compression in WAMP running on Windows Server 2008?

I searched the net and I followed these steps given here: http://www.zigpress.com/2009/04/09/enabling-gzip-on-wamp/.

But after restarting my WAMP the icon got yellow not green.

Than followed this post: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,93406.

Again the same problem my WAMP icon after restarting gets yellow.

This is the code I put in Apache *httpd.conf*:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript   application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Did you try to use _.htaccess_ instead of _httpd.conf_?

Comment: If you have any example please share it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable Deflate compression for resources with WAMP (thus Apache), you can use this following code in your *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It works well for several websites I own.

Answer (score 9):

For use, `AddOutputFilterByType` should also activate the filter module.  Uncomment  `LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so` in the *httpd.conf* file

Comment: +1 In the default WAMP installation, one can enable the deflate module from the UI, but this will not be enough if you want to use `AddOutputFilterByType`.
You will also need to do this.